# Combining delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

The following code

```
Func<int, int> DoWork;
DoWork = x => x + 5;  // ignored
DoWork += y => y + 1; // used
Console.WriteLine(DoWork(2)); // 2 + 1 = 3
```

returns 3, because only the latest added lambda is being processed - the previous methods are being ignored. In case of an `Action<>`, all Methods are being processed.

**Question:** Is there a use case for "adding"/ `Delegate.Combine` Funcs, when the previous ones are being overwritten each time I add another delegate?

Comment: You can have `DoWork = y => DoWork(y) + 1` to wrap the current `DoWork` within a new labmda, which in turn becomes the new `DoWork`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "previous ones" don't get overwritten. They all will be invoked, but only the return value of the last one is being returned.

The C# spec (15.4 Delegate invocation) explains it:

> If the delegate invocation includes output parameters or a return value, their final value will come from the invocation of the last delegate in the list.

---

To test it, try something like:

```
DoWork = x => { Console.WriteLine(x + 5); return x + 5; };
DoWork += y => { Console.WriteLine(y + 1); return y + 1; };

Console.WriteLine(DoWork(2)); // 2 + 1 = 3
```

It will print

```
7
3
3
```

The most common use case is probably using multiple event handlers subscribing to the same event.

Comment: @fubo If you want to read more, I suggest reading [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/chapter2/events.aspx).